# Apply a modifier as a shapekey into existing shapekey or merge shapekeys?

Tags: modifiers, shape-keys

I am making a shapekey of a model shrinkwrapped to another model. The shrinkmap modifier is too inaccurate to wrap to the model alone. So, my first step was to roughly hand position the geometry around of the first model around the second, then use shrinkwrap. The rough positioning was done as a shape key. I can then apply shrinkwrap, but its as a separate shapekey. The two do not work well together. I need them to be the same shapekey. How do I apply a modifier to an existing shapekey, or merge/combine/join the two shapekeys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the shape keys dropdown menu there is a function named new shape from mix: set two or more shape keys to the desired value and then choose this function: at 0 you'll have the undeformed mesh, at 1 the combined effect of the different shape keys.

[image]